# How do I access a variable in a class that was defined before in another class?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python library:
There is a class (game) in it is a function that defines a variable (display)
Then there is another class (char) in main, I want to access display in char
How do I do it?

In the past I have tried: self.display, global display, and game.display

```py
class game():
    def __init__(self, disp, width, height):
        self.display = disp # VARIABLE I WANT TO ACCESS
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    class sprite():
        def __init__(self, size, position, image):
            self.image = image
            self.size = size
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.x = position[0]
            self.rect.y = position[1]
            self.x = position[0]
            self.y = position[1]
            self.collisionDirection = 5
            self.hasCollided = False
            self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
            self.velocity = 0

        def render(self):
            self.rect.x = self.x
            self.rect.y = self.y
            self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
            display.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y)) # WHERE I WANT TO ACCESS IT
```

I keep getting AttributeError what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the Game instance to another class. For example

```
# instantiate the game
g = game()
# create an instance of char
c = char(game)
```

assuming the `__init__` of char() looks something like this:

```
class char():
    def __init__(self, game):
        # save a reference to the game object as an attribute
        self.game = game
        # now you can access the game's attributes
        print(self.game.display)
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow that the below example is contrived, and not likely the way you would design pen/paper, but it shows that there are a couple different ways that you can accomplish what you ask.

```
class Pen:
    def __init__(self, thickness, color):
        self.thickness = thickness
        self.color = color


class Paper:
    def __init__(self, pen: Pen):
        self.pen = pen

    def draw(self):
        pen_color = self.pen.color
        return pen_color

    def draw2(self, pen: Pen):
        pen_color = pen.color
        return pen_color


red_pin = Pen(2, 'Red')
blue_pin = Pen(1, 'Blue')

paper = Paper(red_pin)
print(paper.draw())              # prints Red
print(paper.draw2(blue_pin))     # prints Blue
```